# Prove that if a nonsingular Matrix A then the condition number K(A) = $\frac{\sigma_\max}{\sigma_\min}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if a nonsingular Matrix A then
The condition number K(A) = $\frac{\sigma_\max}{\sigma_\min}$ where $\sigma_\max$ is the largest singular values and  $\sigma_\min$ is the shortest singular values  of $A$.

Comment: What is your definition of the condition number?

Comment: $||A^-1||*||A||$

Comment: $||A||=\sigma_{max}$ and $||A^{-1}||=\sigma_{min}$.